# How to hide marker while showing cluster in Google Map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I use Google Map and Google-Maps-iOS-Utils for an app.

How to hide markers while showing only the cluster?

[image]

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: you means you don't want to show location pin?

Comment: Can you provide codes?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni yes

Comment: @JackyShek my codes are codes Google. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: your code must be something wrong, please provide your own code which help us to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class CustomClusterRenderer: GMUDefaultClusterRenderer {

    let GMUAnimationDuration: Double = 0.5
    var mapView: GMSMapView?

    override init(mapView: GMSMapView, clusterIconGenerator iconGenerator: GMUClusterIconGenerator) {
        super.init(mapView: mapView, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
        self.mapView = mapView
    }

    func markerWith(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, from: CLLocationCoordinate2D, userData: AnyObject, clusterIcon: UIImage, animated: Bool) -> GMSMarker {

        let initialPosition = animated ? from : position
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: initialPosition)
        marker.userData = userData

        marker.icon = clusterIcon
        marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        marker.map = mapView
        if animated {
            CATransaction.begin()
            CAAnimation.init().duration = GMUAnimationDuration
            marker.layer.latitude = position.latitude
            marker.layer.longitude = position.longitude
            CATransaction.commit()
        }
        return marker
    }

    func getCustomUIImageItem(userData: AnyObject) -> UIImage {
        if let item = userData as? Marker {
            return item.merkerIcon
        }
        return UIImage()
    }

    override func shouldRender(as cluster: GMUCluster, atZoom zoom: Float) -> Bool {
        print("Zoom Level is \(zoom) , and result is \(zoom<=14)")
        return zoom <= 14;
    }


}


class Marker: NSObject, GMUClusterItem {

    var position: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var estate: Estate

    init(estate: Estate) {

        self.estate = estate
        self.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: estate.latitude,longitude: estate.longitude)

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

add one line on class GMUDefaultClusterRenderer.m

```
     static const NSUInteger kGMUMinClusterSize = 2;
```

problem resolved

Answer (score 0):

simple answer is that Go to your pod file or if you add manualy go to the class GMUDefaultClusterRenderer.m

simple is that change the top line

```
     static const NSUInteger kGMUMinClusterSize = 2;
```

your probelm resolved thanks

hope that will help you